# setState in infinite loop inside render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I perform the same `setState` inside `map` but outside render / avoid the infinite loop that is:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
> repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
> componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested.

```
class MyComponent {
  render() {
    var images = [
      "https://i.picsum.photos/id/912/500/300.jpg?hmac=m-mTOMKlGcXQHDObNABzzeFPUPMuBVHr2l4rhrGjnmQ",
      "https://i.picsum.photos/id/912/500/300.jpg?hmac=m-mTOMKlGcXQHDObNABzzeFPUPMuBVHr2l4rhrGjnmQ",
      "https://i.picsum.photos/id/912/500/300.jpg?hmac=m-mTOMKlGcXQHDObNABzzeFPUPMuBVHr2l4rhrGjnmQ",
      "",
      "",
    ];
    return (
      <div class="row thumbnailview">
        {images.map((image, index) => {
          if (image.length < 2) {
            return (
              <div className="col thumbnails hidden">
                <img src={image} className="thumbnail" />
              </div>
            );
          }
          if (image.length >= 2) {
            return (
              <div className="col thumbnails">
                <img src={image} className="thumbnail" onClick={this.setState({ imageSrc: { image } })} />
              </div>
            );
          }
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your onClick should look like this:

```
onClick={() => this.setState({imageSrc:{image}})}
```

NOT this:

```
onClick={this.setState({imageSrc: {image}})}
```

Comment: Thanks. The setState is not working correctly now as in imageSrc becomes [object Object] instead of the link on onclick. Do you know why"

Comment: @user123928 You are setting it to an object, not a string. You likely mean `this.setState({ imageSrc: image })` instead.

Comment: @user123928 that's a different question - but I have a feeling youi might have wanted it to look like this: `this.setState({imageSrc:image})`

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `setState` during render in

```
onClick={this.setState({imageSrc: {image}})}
```

What you really want there is

```
onClick={() => this.setState({imageSrc: {image}})}
```

i.e. to wrap that setState in a function that only gets called when you click on the image.